# Page Goes Blank Using File_Exists

Tags: php

I'm checking to see if a file or directory exists using -

```
 <?php  
 $filename = "../ads/";
 if(file_exists($filename)) ?>
```

It works but when I'm NOT in the root.  If I'm in another directory .... **For Example** - If I'm in the "ads" directory and I view the-ads.php the page goes blank because in the header I have the file_exists code.

IF I remove .. from ../ads/ the page displays like it should.

What should I do? I need .. in the path ../ads/.

Comment: You should use a proper framework/autoloader system, that does not rely transparently on file paths. Composer is your friend!

Comment: `$filename = dirname(__DIR__) . '/ads/'` or use `$_ENV['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` to make the paths more predictable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by creating a config and mapping the

../ads/  AS  ../../ads/

In the config in ads dir I added

```
define('THEURL','../../ads/');
```

In the header code added THEURL in replace of ../ads/